# Creating an Icicle Chart using Python Visual in Power BI

Tags: python, powerbi, icicle-diagram

I am trying to create an icicle chart for a company hierarchy. Our company uses Power BI for it's reports and I can see that there isn't an icicle visual within Power BI but that one can be created using the Python Visual option. I have a little bit of basic experience with Python but am struggling with the code within Power BI.

I have a data table within Power BI called "Data", which contains columns "Employee", "FirstManager", "SecondManager" and "Value". The "Value" column simply contains a value of 1 for every employee so that the icicle chart will be the same width for each employee.

I would like the chart to show as "SecondManager" > "FirstManager" > "Employee".

Would anyone be able to help with the code for this within the Power BI Python Visual? I am specifically struggling with how the Power BI table is added to the dataframe.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the docs here, it's plain vanilla: [Create Power BI visuals by using Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-visuals)